# PHP - check if a file is EOF

Tags: php, file

Is it possible to check whether a file is completed(EOF) or is partially(corrupted)

I try :

```
$_file = @fopen($filePath, "r");
$isComplete = feof($_file);
fclose($file);
```

but it return empty.

Comment: A literal google search of your question gives you the answer, you can test it yourself [here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=PHP+check+if+a+file+is+EOF&oq=PHP+check+if+a+file+is+EOF&aqs=chrome..69i64j69i57.5252j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I mean, you see for instance this thread floating by.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: i google , but the feof doesn't really return something that meaning complete or partial of the file

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`while(){}`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop for that, as:

```
$fh = fopen("alphabets.txt", "r"); 
while (!feof($fh)) { 
    $line = fgets($fh); 
    echo $line . "<br/>";
}

echo 'File is completed <br />';
```

Which will obviosuly iterate through the file's line one by one and exits as it reaches the end

I assuming  your file contains a letters from a-h, this will be your output

```
a 
b 
c 
d 
e 
f 
g 
h
File is completed
```

Comment: Couldn't this be `while($line = fgets($fh) !== false){//code...}`?

Comment: Yeah. That's perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, if is basically the same if you remove the two variables and echo's

Comment: the code is working, but it  feof doesn't really tell whether the file is complete or partial

Comment: @LouisLee What do you mean complete/partial? If the file is complete when the loop is complete

Comment: If you want to know the file is not corrupted, use [is_readable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) or something like that